# Django: Logging configuration location

Tags: python, django, logging

I have on top of my views.py the following line to enable logging:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

To change the loglevel to debug for all loggers I have put the following lines into the settings.py:

```
if DEBUG:
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

But still if I log something with loglevel INFO in my views.py it's not getting shown. Why?

Comment: Please write how you log something in view. You may be using different logger with different log level.

Comment: @Pax0r I log something with `logger.info('hi')`

Comment: Please post your setting's `LOGGING_CONFIG`. NB : all you have to know about logging config in Django is documented here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I read the docs about logging... but it isn't mentioned where to put own logging customization...

Comment: @ProgrammingPete well yes it is - you can either customize the `settings.LOGGING` dict (simplest solution) or completely bypass Django and configure the whole thing by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get any logging for something outside the `django` hierarchy you have to configure the logger for your own hierarchy (or configure the "root" logger but you might get much more than you asked for) - Django's default only configures the `django` hierarchy. You can [see some examples here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#examples), specially the "fairly complex logging setup" (which is actually quite simple compared to ours but well):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'special': {
            '()': 'project.logging.SpecialFilter',
            'foo': 'bar',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'myproject.custom': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the last entry - this is how you add logging for your own project/apps (or for third part apps or libs FWIW).

wrt/ changing the level according to the `DEBUG` flag, what I do is  to define a `DEFAULT_LOGGING_LEVEL` before:

```
# settings.py

DEBUG = <....>
# ....

DEFAULT_LOGGING_LEVEL = "DEBUG" if DEBUG else "INFO"
```

and then use it for all loggers except the ones where I want something more specific :

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(name)s %(module)s '
                      '%(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
            },
        'simple': {
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z",
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] %(name)s %(message)s',
            },
        },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
            }
        },

    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
            },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'include_html': True
            },
        'warn_admins': {
            'level': 'WARN',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'include_html': True
            },
        },
    'loggers': {
        # ----------------------------------------
        # general
        # ----------------------------------------
        # make sure we have anything >= WARN whatsoever
        'root': {
            'handlers':  ["console"],
            'level': "WARN",
            'formatter': "verbose",
            },

        # ----------------------------------------
        # apps loggers - django (default)
        # ----------------------------------------
        'django': {
            'handlers':  ["console",],
            'level': "INFO",
            'formatter': "verbose",
            'propagate': True,
            },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
            },

        # ----------------------------------------
        # app loggers - third part
        # ----------------------------------------
        'reportlab.platypus': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
            },

        # ----------------------------------------
        # app loggers - our own apps
        # ----------------------------------------
        'account': {
            'handlers':  ["console",],
            'level': DEFAULT_LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
            },
        'core': {
            'handlers':  ["console",],
            'level': DEFAULT_LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
            },
        'shop': {
            'handlers':  ["console",],
            'level': DEFAULT_LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
            },
        'shop.views': {
            'handlers':  ["console", "warn_admins"],
            'level': DEFAULT_LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
            },

    # etc
```

As you can notice I don't have to manually call on the `logging` module itself, all is done thru the `LOGGING` dict (and Djano takes care of passing it to `logging.dictConfig()`).

NB : The `dictConfig` format is fairly documented so I won't explain it here.

Comment: And where do I have to put the Code?

Comment: It's writen in all letters in both the documentation and my answer - did you actually read them ?

Comment: So it goes to settings.py?

Comment: it goes in your settings module however it's named, yes.